# WordPress navigation only shows post of page one, even if on page two

Tags: navigation

Got a little problem hopefully I can get some help. I noticed that after I added a "sort post by" code to my index my navigation broke. If you click on page two you still get the contents of page one. I did a little digging and found the problem, only thing is I not sure how to fix it. Here is the loop from my index page. Now I need to exclude a selected category from the main loop, that's the first part. The second part is if I add $orderby to the query_posts string (second to the last line) then the navigation breaks. If I remove it then it works. I tried to have to query_posts strings, but that didn't work out. Anyway to make this work or do I have to give up one for the other?

```
        <?php
    $featcat = get_option($shortname.'_featured_category');      
    $category_id = get_cat_ID($featcat);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged'))?get_query_var('paged'):1;
$q = array();
$q['category__not_in'] = array($category_id);
$q['paged'] = $paged;
query_posts($q.$orderby);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `$q` is and array and `$orderby` is a string. So `$q.$orderby` doesn't make sense. (Untested) but remove `$orderby` and try

```
$q['orderby']='title';
```

(The `orderby` key can have any value given [in this list in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).). Also, it would be neater to use this syntax:

```
$q = array(
    'category__not_in'=> array($category_id),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby'=>'title',
);
query_posts($q);
```

---

#### Update

If you you are trying to make this compatible with the WP-PostRatings plug-in, instead of using the query string`&r_sortby=highest_rated&r_orderby=desc`, you can put it in array format:

```
$q = array(
    'category__not_in'=> array($category_id),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'highest_rated',
    'orderby'=>'meta value',
    'order'=>'DESC',
);
query_posts($q);
```

*Note, I've not tested this nor checked the plug-in', but 'highest_rated' should be the meta key of the post's rating. [See the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) for more details.*

Comment: Thanks for the cleaned up code, but I need to have two query_post in the loop. One for the $q and then one for $orderby. I have a function that the post get sorted after a user selects to order them by "top rated", "Most viewed" and "Latest". That was the reason I was using $q.$orderby.

Comment: Then whatever that `$orderby` is you pass it to `$q['orderby']`.

Comment: Still no luck. It needs to have that query_post($orderby) to work.

Comment: I can't see why. Can you give an example of a value for $orderby?

Comment: This is part of the code from the order function. case 'rated' : $orderby = '&r_sortby=highest_rated&r_orderby=desc';

Comment: You can translate that into array format. Assuming the rating is stored with meta key 'highest_rated', see updated answer, if it's not you simply need to change 'highest_rated' to the meta key.